# How to construct an association list of functions in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I want to do something like this:

```
'((function1 . '(lambda (args) "DOCSTRING" ))
  (function2 . '(lambda (args) "DOCSTRING" )))
```

But "dot" just opens what stands after it:

`((function1 quote (lambda (args) "DOCSTRING")) (function2 quote (lambda (args) "DOCSTRING")))`

I know it works like it should, but how to correct it in this case?
So that I could get functions by a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lambda` self-quotes:

```
(setq falist
      '((function1 . (lambda (args) "DOCSTRING" 1))
        (function2 . (lambda (args) "DOCSTRING" 2))))
(funcall (cdr (assoc 'function2 falist)) 1)
; => 2
```

Comment: Thanks, can see now that the problem wasn't in this part of my code. (I also tried without qoutes)

Comment: @WillNess, it's not bad at all, actually makes sense to me. Compare to https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: ``(setq falist `((func1 . ,(lambda (args) "DOCSTR1" 1))))`` in Common Lisp... Elisp reader I guess replaces any nested lambda form with its value, a self-quoting function object.... Bad or good, but *different*. :) Thnx for the link, had a blast! :)

Comment: also, see [Philip Wadler "Why calculating is better than Scheming"](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dat/miranda/wadler87.pdf), a critique of Lisp's fickle meaning of `quote`, among other things. :)

Comment: @WillNess It doesn't.  But a lambda form evaluates to a function object, so a quoted lambda happens to work most of the time. You should **never** quote lambda forms, though!

Comment: @aboabo Never put lambda forms in a fully quoted list.  This prevents the byte compiler and the interpreter from inspecting then, and thus prevents byte compilation of the lambda, and breaks lexical scope! Instead, use a quasi quote as suggested by Will Ness!

Comment: @lunaryorn aha, so it's not the reader; it's the evaluation rules. Because the code as is in this answer doesn't work in CLisp (I checked). `(funcall '(lambda(a)2) 1)` says `"FUNCALL: argument (LAMBDA (A) 2) is not a function."`. Attempt to repeat the answer's code results in the same error: `"FUNCALL: argument (LAMBDA (ARGS) "DOCSTRING" 2) is not a function."`. So Elisp allows this, though Common Lisp rejects. Interesting.